# Valid date method logic?

Tags: java, logic

I'm having trouble understanding why this method makes all dates I input be returned as true(valid). The only part of this method that works perfectly is the leap year statement. I've tried defining another variable called isValid and returning that as true and adding a if statement to return the method as either true or false, however, that only worked for some dates, which I dont quite understand either. Can anyone tell me why this method is flawed?

```
public boolean isValid()
{
  if ( month == Month.JAN || month == Month.MAR || 
        month == Month.MAY || month == Month.JUL
        || month == Month.OCT || month == Month.OCT 
        || month == Month.DEC && day <= Month.DAYS_ODD )
     return true;
  if ( month == Month.APR || month == Month.JUN 
        || month == Month.SEP
        || month == Month.NOV && day <= Month.DAYS_EVEN )
     return true;
  boolean leapYear = false;
  if ( year % Month.QUADRENNIAL == 0 || year % Month.CENTENNIAL == 0
        || year % Month.QUATERCENTENNIAL == 0 )
     leapYear = true;
  if ( leapYear )
     if ( month == Month.FEB && day <= Month.DAYS_FEB + 1)
        return true;
  if ( month == Month.FEB && day <= Month.DAYS_FEB )
     return true;
  return false;
```

}

```
public class Month 
{
   public static final int JAN = 1;
   public static final int FEB = 2;
   public static final int MAR = 3;
   public static final int APR = 4;
   public static final int MAY = 5;
   public static final int JUN = 6;
   public static final int JUL = 7;
   public static final int AUG = 8;
   public static final int SEP = 9;
   public static final int OCT = 10;
   public static final int NOV = 11;
   public static final int DEC = 12;
   public static final int DAYS_ODD = 31;
   public static final int DAYS_EVEN = 30;
   public static final int DAYS_FEB = 28;
   public static final int QUADRENNIAL = 4;
   public static final int CENTENNIAL = 100;
   public static final int QUATERCENTENNIAL = 400;
}
```

Comment: The logic is all wrong. If the month is valid all the following checks are skipped.  In fact, if ***any*** single component of the date is valid the method will return `true` even if all the others are invalid.

Comment: You need to use parentheses around your `OR` sections.

Comment: @JimGarrison Correct me if i'm wrong, but i thought that the logic behind my first if statement is "if the month is January or the month is march or the month is may... AND there are 31 or less days, then return true. So wouldn't their have to be 2 true components?

Comment: @PM77-1 why? how does this change the code?

Answer (score 0):

The logic for leap year is wrong. it should be like as below.

```
if ( year % Month.QUADRENNIAL == 0
    || year % Month.QUATERCENTENNIAL == 0 )
 leapYear = true;
```

The number which is divisible by 100 is not a Leap year, for example : 1900,  its not a leap year.